# How to create graph out of two layers using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, graph

[image: crmrttbl][image: crimerate][image: landprize]I would like to create a graph of two layers I have. On the one hand is the land price of a certain area and on the other a layer with a crime rate.

First of all, the layer with the land prices doesn't have a table like the crime rate layer. So I can't join them, which was my first intention, the other problem is that I don't even know how to create a table out of that layer (well I do in general but the create table tool won't offer me the land price layer as an option). If someone could explain that to me I guess the rest wouldn't be much of a problem.

Eventually the graph should look something like this (with the crime rate at the x-axis and the land price at the y-axis): 
[image: Graph]

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Arc? Can you not open the .dbf files for each layer, copy the data into excel and create the graph there. You could then save the graph and import into Arc as an image if needed.

Comment: Can you give more information about your data? raster/vector, point/polygon, fields, screenshot of map, ...

Comment: @ MAJ742 i would like to open the dbf file but as i said there is no dbf for the land prize layer.

Comment: @ Jens it is a raster. ill attache the screenshot

Comment: the question is really only about how i can create a table out of the land prize layer so that i can combine it with the table of the crime rate layer. thats actually all i need to know here. i also dont understand why the create table tool is asking me for a table location since im just trying to create a table in the first place

Comment: Can you give more information about crime rate data set (raster/vector, point/polygon, fields, ...)? Do you have ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Comment: yes i do have spatial analyst. the crime rate is raster i attache a screenshot

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the attribute table of crime rate data set?

Comment: ok i added it but how do you think it can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a *zonal statistics* analysis to investigate the relationship between crime rate and land price.

Use [Zonal Statistics as Table (Spatial Analyst) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) with these settings:

`in_zone_data` = crime rate

`zone_field` = label (field of crime rate)

`in_value_raster` = land price

`statistics_type` = all

The result is a table. Use Excel to create a chart.

You find more informaton [How Zonal Statistics works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/How_Zonal_Statistics_works/009z000000wt000000/) in ArcGIS help.